# Excel charts, moving horizontal axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm asking for help with an Excel charting problem concerning the horizontal axis. In this example, you can see that I've set labels to "Low," so they appear along the bottom. But the horizontal axis and its tick marks -- I can't figure out how to move them to the bottom. I'm aware that I could set "Horizontal axis crosses" to -0.16, but that produces a different effect. I just want to move the axis line. I can supply a workbook with this chart and its data.

[Example of what I have and what I'd like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE5Ug.jpg)

Comment: Why would moving the horizontal axis down to cross at -0.16 not produce the effect you want? 
(apart from it then being fixed rather than automated, which is a non-optimal outcome if your datasets vary, but this appears to be long-term trend data so it will be a while until that is an issue)

Comment: That is an option, yes. But we lose the obvious distinction between positive and negative values. Example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think the real X-axis could be moved down.

But as a workaround, we may create another line to shown as X-axis.

[image]

1. Add a colomn, set the value as 0.
2. Right click the chart > Select Data > Add a series in chart.
3. Right click the chart again > Change Chart Type > Combo, set Line and tick seconday Axis for this new series.
   [image]
4. Set No Line for previous X-axis (Horizonal Axis).
   [image]
5. Add the gridline (Such as Primary Major Vertical or Minor Major Vertical) for this chart, this action could make the chart more readble.
   [image]
6. Set No Line and no Lable for the Secondary Vertical (Values) Axis.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Someone suggested making the horizontal axis cross at -16%. This works, but I lose the obvious visual difference between positive and negative values. Example:

[image: Example]